# Python function default argument takes value which is set during first call

Tags: python, function, arguments, default

I have a function with one default argument. This default argument is updated inside the function.
When I call the same function again, I see the argument takes the value which is set during the first call

What's wrong with the following code.

```
def fun(x, data=[]):
    print "entering fun with data = ",data
    data.append(x)

print "calling fun..."
fun(1)
print "calling fun..."
fun(3)
```

Here the output is

```
calling fun...
entering fun with data =  []
calling fun...
entering fun with data =  [1]
```

but I expect the output to be

```
enter code here
calling fun...
entering fun with data =  []
calling fun...
entering fun with data =  []
```

Comment: Why is data an empty list by default?

Comment: The actual scenario is a function which recursively called itself with updated value of data argument. What I see is when I called the same function again from main, I see the data is not empty list but the value which is set during first function call

Comment: Yes, this is a common Python gotcha. Read the answers at the linked duplicate

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see the linked duplicate with same issue